# Unit testing WatchService

Tags: java, watchservice

How can I unit test a watchservice like this:

```
/**
 * Function to look for changes in a determinate directory
 * @param directory is the directory where to look for the changes
 * @return return a boolean that is true if have changes or false if not
 */

private static boolean watchDirectory(final String directory){

    boolean flag = false;

    Path path = Paths.get(directory);
    try {
        // get watch service which will monitor the directory
        WatchService watcher = path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
        // associate watch service with the directory to listen to the event types
        path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        System.out.println("\nMonitoring directory for changes...");
        // listen to events
        WatchKey watchKey = watcher.take();
        // get list of events as they occur
        List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watchKey.pollEvents();

        for (WatchEvent event : events) {
            flag = false;
            //check if the events refers to a new file created
            if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                flag = true;

                System.out.println("Created: " + event.context().toString() + " ;");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

It is looking for changes in a directory, if a new file is created it returns a flag with value true, if i didnt find changes return the flag as false.

Comment: first of all, you don't directly unit test private methods, you test them through testing the methods that call it. as for the checks of other classes, you'll need to mock them

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JUnit** for testing WatchService.

**Reference** : https://github.com/bbejeck/Java-7/blob/master/src/test/java/bbejeck/nio/files/watch/WatchDirectoryTest.java

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the JUnit rule `TemporaryFolder`, it allows one to create temporary folder and temporary files. The test just has to inject the temporary path in the production code of the tested unit.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
private File etcHost;

@Before
public void set_file_with_content() throws Exception {
    etcHost = temporaryFolder.newFile();        
}

@Test
public void on_etc_hosts_change_do_something() throws IOException {
    // given
    try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(etcHost.toPath(), UTF_8, WRITE)) {
        bufferedWriter.write("127.0.0.1 xxxxx.local");
    }

    // when
    try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(etcHost.toPath(), UTF_8, WRITE)) {
        bufferedWriter.write("127.1.1.1 zzzzz.local");
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.write("127.0.0.1 xxxxx.local");
    }

    // then
    ...
}
```

This may work for simple notifications. But you need to be aware that the `WatchService` depends on the underlying implementation which depends on the OS and the file-system. That means that if you develop on Windows and that the code runs on Linux, this code may not work exactly the same way. Even more if you develop on Linux and the production run on Linux too, but the way the production mounts file or folder may impede the ability to watch a path correctly ; this may typically happen in containers.

---

The code above looks incorrect to me, first `.take()` is not in a loop, so once events are polled the method will exit. And `WatchKey` is not reset after he handling of each event. You may want something like that :

```
try (WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
    watchedParent.register(watchService, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_CREATE, OVERFLOW, ENTRY_DELETE);

    WatchKey wk;
    while ((wk = watchService.take()) != null) {
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {
            if(event.kind() == OVERFLOW) { continue; }

            Path changedRelativePath = (Path) event.context();
            if (watchedFile.getFileName().equals(changedRelativePath)) {
                ...
            }
        }
        wk.reset();
    }
}
```